# No MVC4 templates in Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2012 Pro and noticed that I don't have the option to create ASP.Net MVC4 project.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by copying the folder WPT from the install iso to my desktop. In this folder there are four msi's

- aspnetmvc3.msi
- aspnetmvc3vs11tools.msi
- aspnetmvc4.msi
- aspnetmvc4vs11tools.msi

I uninstalled and reinstalled these in the listed order and started VS2012, the MVC templates then appeared in my new project dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 2012 Pro but for 2010 Express I needed to install it separately.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4